# how to fill the remaining screen with table

Tags: android, layout

i have the following  layout in my application [image: layout]
The Ok, QUIT buttons are not there.

now i want to distribute the space after the textview , with the table of 3 rows having 0-9,C, D buttons. I want the three rows to span the remaining space equally.

please tell me how to do it. I am posting my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


android:id="@+id/main_layout"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="100" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="clear"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/table" >
</View>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to build my `RelativeLayout`s from the bottom up and then from the top down. Here is an example of what I do. The butons will be at the bottom and then I'll place something above it whose height is `fill_parent` -- this has been working well for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons" >

        ....

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```